# How to I install Glassfish on Ubuntu from the command line?

Tags: installation, command-line, glassfish

I have a Linux machine (Ubuntu) and I installed GlassFish and everything worked fine.  The thing is, I was using Linux from the desktop UI and the installer featured a graphical wizard.

I am wondering, if I create a Linux virtual machine on Amazon EC2 or Rackspace, I can only access the Linux from the command line using SSH.

How do I install GlassFish from the command line?  Won't the graphic install wizard attempt to display and fail?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gunzip glassfish-3.1.1-web.zip`

Comment: thanks -- I hadn't thought of that, but that will work.  Although the graphical wizard walks through some basic setup, would be nice to be able to use it.

Comment: After this,  how do I make it start up on boot?

Comment: @user7054 By reading a tutorial, like [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadi.html) or any other.

Comment: @DaveNewton The link shows how to start it manually, not on boot.

Comment: @user7054 ... I found this the same way I found that one, by searching: https://blogs.oracle.com/foo/entry/how_to_run_glassfish_v3

Comment: why the web version, and not the full version?

Comment: @Thufir Because three years ago that's the one I happened to have.

Answer (score 3):

You could use X forwarding when connecting with SSH. Then, the graphical installer should work.

See also:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/198846/remote-x-session-on-ec2
- https://superuser.com/questions/249045/x11-forwarding-from-amazon-ec2-ami

Answer (score 0):

`sudo aptitude install glassfish`, assuming the package name is `glassfish`. Whether you connect over SSH or not is completely irrelevant.

Comment: I believe Robert wants to install Glassfish v3, which is not available from Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: I'll be happy to update the answer if the OP adds information about where the graphical installer (or PPA?) was obtained.

Comment: @tripleee - I downloaded the installer "glassfish-3.1.1-unix.sh" from here: http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.1-final.html

Comment: @tripleee - is "aptitude" a ubuntu-specific feature?  just thinking (since I use a Mac for development) it would be nice to learn how to do things in a standard cross-platform UNIX way.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Robert Hume: aptitude, apt-get, synaptic are tools that are specific to .deb packages.  There is no universal packaging format, beyond `tar` files containing a `README`, although there are many contenders to become the One True Standard.  See also RPM, OSX Fink, the Solaris package manager, *BSD ports, Gentoo Portage, etc.  And http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system

Answer (score 0):

This will guide you through all the installation steps from command line: http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-311-on-ubuntu

Comment: This link appears to be dead. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.