# Java problems installing Glassfish 3.1.2 on Ubuntu Lucid

Tags: 10.04, java, update-alternatives, glassfish

I'm trying to install **Glassfish v3.1.2** on **Ubuntu 10.04** by obtaining corresponding **.sh** from Oracle website and running `sudo ./glassfish-installer-file.sh`. However following error appears:

> Could not locate a suitable jar utility. Please ensure that you have Java 6 or newer installed on your system and accessible in your PATH or by setting JAVA_HOME

The problem is that **$JAVA_HOME** (and also **$JDK_HOME** which I think is superfluous) is being correctly set in `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
export JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin:so-on
```

and it's possible to execute all programs from **$JAVA_HOME/bin** directory from console (including **jar** program).

Now, what I noticed is that some time ago I installed **java**, **javac** and **javaws** specifically using **sudo update-alternatives --install ...** command into **/usr/lib/bin** folder.

So I tried to install **jar** in the same way (using **sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/jar" "jar" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_35/bin/jar" 1**) and the initial problem was solved - above error didn't appear when I tried to install **Glassfish** again. But another problem appeared - it looks like during installation GF installer couldn't find **keytool** program this time.

I'm not very happy with installing several dozens of programs from Java bin folder, so the main question is: is there significant difference from the point of view of other programs (like **Glassfish** installer) between:

- installing some program using **sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/program-name program-name /path/to/program-name 1**
  and
- simply adding it to **$PATH** variable?

Or this can be considered as bug in **Glassfish** installer?

Thanks in advance

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/a/61513/45156   for correct answer.  duplicate q?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to I install Glassfish on Ubuntu from the command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61510/how-to-i-install-glassfish-on-ubuntu-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish is a complex beast and there's a WHOLE lot more to getting it running than just glassfish itself.  Tutorial here: http://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/glassfish/installing-glassfish-311-on-ubuntu

You'll need to knock out a lot of prerequisites - including an Oracle-specific Java - before you can run the glassfish installer itself.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing out - will try that when I have time